# Kafka simple consumer and message size - Does it read partial messsage?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using the simple consumer to read from the kafka topic and have a question regarding how the fetch size is related to the size of the messages in the topic.

Lets say, each of my message in the topic is 10 kb.

When i consume starting from offset 0 with the fetch size of 16 kb (just for the sake of this question), does it read 1 complete message and another partial message for 6kb?

The [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-Overview) states the following, but i don't see it happening

> As an optimization the server is allowed to return a partial message
>   at the end of the message set. Clients should handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look deeper on how [message sets and messages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-Messagesets) are encoded you'll notice that they are usually preceded by a size in bytes (unlike all other structures where the size is an item count), so the client first reads the size of a message set and then reads N bytes of the actual message set. The same thing with a message - first the size is read, and then the actual message of size N.

Without the optimization Kafka server would check if the fetch response has exceeded the fetch size AND rollback the last message.

The optimization here is pretty simple: instead of keeping track where should it rollback to form a pretty fetch response without cut messages it simply accumulates messages until the fetch size is exceeded AND just cuts everything that exceeds the fetch size.

By saying `Clients should handle this case` it means that any wire protocol implementor should be ready that a message set of size 100 for example might not have 100 more bytes to read and hence the client should not fail and consider this as normal behaviour.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand still.  For example, there are 10 messages in the topic each with a size of 12 bytes. Lets assume that the fetch size is 50 kb. Do you mean to say that, it reads 4 messages and when reads the 5th message, since it has exceeded 50 kb, it will truncate the 5th message?

Comment: Not sure whether it will always happen but yes, there is a chance the 5th message will just be truncated and this should be ignored by client. In fact if you're using some ready consumer implementation, you won't even see this 5th message in your FetchResponse (or whatever it exposes to you).

Comment: Thanks. The 5th message will be fetched when it the request is sent again, am i right?

Comment: @ManikandanKannan Exactly